# Component that responds to amperage

Tags: components, amperage

I am extremely new to electronics, so please let me know if I have no idea what I am talking about.

Basically, I know there are transistors, resistors, capacitors, etc. These are all components as I understand it.

I was wondering if there was a component, material, or element that only outputs when its input has a certain amplitude.

Like, say the threshold was 1 A, it would not output anything at 0.99 A, and would output fully at 1 A.

Comment: What do you mean by "outputs" @Walter?

Comment: Simple, real components don't have such sharp and well-defined thresholds. Not even diodes.

Comment: It would help if you defined how many terminals this theoretical device would have, and what you mean by "input" and "output".

Comment: Diodes are non-linear and become highly conductive small resistors above it's rated voltage and systems can be design to do what you suggest, but not single components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was wondering if there was a component, material, or element that only outputs when its input has a certain amplitude.

A solenoid with an iron rod that protrudes some distance from the coil, its end surface stuck to a short magnet. There is a sharp transition from the rod staying attached to the magnet to the rod being detached. You can add a contact pair between the rod and the magnet, and if you're careful in design, you got yourself a 0.1% accurate current comparator. This is a variant of a device known as a current relay, with a bit more nonlinearity thrown in to make it more sensitive.

The same can be implemented using electromagnetic forces in a MEMS "teeter-totter": two solenoids would attract opposite ends of the beam, and the beam would flip as the relative current magnitudes flip sign. A capacitive sensor detects whether the beam is still "stuck left" or "stuck right" or "away".

A galvanometer mounted so that the pointer's "zero" position is horizontal is a good current discriminator as well. Add a bit of mass at the tip of the pointer, and let the tip rest on a stationary contact. The pointer is the second, moving contact. Once the coil current passes a threshold needed to null out the moment due to the weight of the pointer, the pointer begins to move away from the stationary contact, opening the circuit. With careful experimental design - at which point it's a specialized instrument rather than a meter - threshold tolerances between 50-100nA can be achieved. I'm sure one could do better than that.

A current-controlled laser source can have the beam split into to beams with unequal powers (say 2:1). The more powerful split beam illuminates an optically nonlinear material. Once the beam power exceeds a threshold, the material is fully optically saturated, and all the excess beam power passes through. The less powerful split beam, and the beam passing through the saturated material, go into a photometer (an optical power null detector). The photometer can be electronic or old-school with human eye looking at the screen (potentially phosphor-coated to convert IR into visible light), comparing brightness across the field split. Once the laser power reaches a certain threshold, both beams will have equal power at the detector, and we have the indication of a threshold. A wonderful kludge, by the way.

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is no, there is no such (fundamental) component that does what you describe.

There are components that are primarily sensitive to current (BJTs, for example), and you could certainly construct a circuit to do what you want using them. You could use a current transformer or transimpedance amplifier or shunt resistor and op-amp, or... the list goes on and on.

Your question isn't flawed per-se, but what you are describing is a higher-level system than just a single fundamental component like a resistor, capacitor, inductor, transistor, etc. so whatever circuit you make to solve this problem (switch only at a particular current threshold) will be some combination of basic components.

Answer (score 6):

It's not one component but a piece of equipment known as a 'current relay'.

Here's an easy-to-understand schematic.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If I may, your question can be expanded to, "How are electronic quantities measured, compared to a threshold, and then indicated when the threshold is exceeded". There is no single component that can do what you ask. A network of several components is required.

The basic device is called a comparator. It has high amplification so that its output changes state with a small difference in voltage between its **two** inputs. The symbol shown is the same as an operational amplifier, so be careful when you research or purchase.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdeqLx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where a current is to be compared to a reference, first the unknown current is converted to a voltage, then amplified if necessary then finally applied to a voltage comparator. The circuit is shown below. In this diagram the same symbol is used twice, once as an operational amplifier and once as a voltage comparator. If Vx is large enough then the amplifier may not be necessary. The amplifier includes the operational amplifier and the two resistors.
The sense resistor is used to convert the current Ix to the voltage Vx so that it can work with the comparator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fatpth.png)</sup>

The diagrams shown indicate the basic operation for the function that you describe. Sometimes sensing the current can be challenging. There are other comp0nents required to make this work so enjoy your research.

If you need help with something specific please ask more questions. There is a schematic editor called Circuit lab as a tool in the question editor.

If you want precision this is the way to go.

Comment: Whilst I greatly enjoy the lateral thinking of some of the other answers, if you actually want to *build* such a device @Walter this is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

A fuse is fairly close:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fazs6d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If F1 is a 1A fuse then the voltage across it will be fairly low for current < 1. If the current is increased to a larger current, then after some time delay, the fuse may open and VM1 will read 12V.

A real fuse is not a precision device, and it may carry a current of 1.5A or 2A for a while before opening.

If F1 is a polyfuse it will reset once it has cooled down.

Note that there is also a small (in most contexts) voltage across the fuse when it is carrying current.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for seems to be something like a Hall Effect switch, which is actually a Hall sensor with other circuitry to determine set point and hysteresis. These devices basically sense a magnetic field, but that can be generated from a coil of wire and current. Here are some references.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect_sensor

https://www.bristolwatch.com/hall_effect/index.htm

https://www.circuitstoday.com/hall-effect-switch

[Here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmag5124.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1662158812583&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.com%252F) is a Hall effect magnetic sensor with switch output, but you need to mount it on a PCB track or use a coil of wire:

And [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08XZHW3Z1) is an adjustable AC current sensing switch.